# Facebook php SDK Just display Name and ID

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I create SDK facebook v2.3 in CI 2, but i just got Name and ID user detail, i need email detail from user login.

Result of print_r is

> Array ( [name] => Alan El-nino Malmsteen [id] => 1111310922216558 )

I have create permission email but still not work

```
public function FBLogin()
{
$this->load->library('facebook');
$login_url = $this->facebook->login_url();
$get_user = $this->facebook->get_user();
if($get_user){ 
    //echo $this->facebook->get_email();
    print_r($get_user);
}else{
   redirect('login_url');
}
```

And Library Facebook.php

```
            <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
        if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
          session_start();
        }
        // Autoload the required files
        require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/Facebook/autoload.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

        require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

        require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
        require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

        use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
        class Facebook {
          var $ci;
          var $helper;
          var $session;
          var $permissions;
          public function __construct() {
            $this->ci =& get_instance();
            $this->permissions = $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');
            // Initialize the SDK
            FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook') );
            $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $this->ci->config->item('redirect_url', 'facebook') );
            if ( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') ) {
              $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') );
              // Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
              try {
                if ( ! $this->session->validate() ) {
                  $this->session = null;
                }
              } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                // Catch any exceptions
                $this->session = null;
              }
            } else {
              // No session exists
              try {
                $this->session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
              } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
                // When Facebook returns an error
              } catch( Exception $ex ) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
              }
            }
            if ( $this->session ) {
              $this->ci->session->set_userdata( 'fb_token', $this->session->getToken() );
              $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->getToken() );
            }
          }
          /**
           * Returns the login URL.
           */
          public function login_url() {
            return $this->helper->getLoginUrl( $this->permissions );
          }
          /**
           * Returns the current user's info as an array.
           */
          public function get_user() {
            if ( $this->session ) {
              /**
               * Retrieve User’s Profile Information
               */
              // Graph API to request user data
              $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ) )->execute();
              // Get response as an array
              $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
              return $user;
            }
            return false;
          }
        }
```

Comment: First of all, check if your app is actually _using_ v2.3 – look what API version it shows on the first page in app dashboard. If that says v2.4, then it means you can’t go any “lower”. And that would mean, you need to go read the changelog – what has changed in regard to fields returned by default is described in there. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Comment: And are you _sure_ you have the `email` permission? I don’t see you asking for it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I need to fill all facebook configuration, specially logo,email, privacy police url and description via facebook API developer page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$request = (new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/me/?fields=friends,id,name,birthday,email,picture,gender,location,address,email,hometown'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

I think in new version, you need to explicitly call these. Also make sure that you've email permissions in APP.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is if you are using old SDK and calling new Facebook API Version.

Eg. I am using PHP SDK **3.2.3** version and call Facebook API **2.6**. I only able to get ID and Name as returned value.

The Access Token generated by the SDK only can get back these 2 values. You can use graph API and test the access token to double confirm is it because of the old API version.